# Can we use ejs variables inside <script> tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I need to use the variable created with ejs syntax to the script part of the file.
For eg:

```
<% var test = 101; %>
<script>
  var getTest = <%= test  %>;
  console.log(getTest); 
</script>
```

But in the line `var getTest = <%= test  %>;` it shows me error `Expression expected` Like below image.

[image]

Is there any solution to this?

*Here is the Static HTML code snippet for a better understanding of the use case.*

```
<HTML>
<body>
  <!--The below values are dynamic and passed from another file but here we kept it static. -->
  <%  var lineChartLabels = ["Feb 01"], lineChartData = [120]; %>
    <canvas id="totalViewChart" style="width: 100%; height: 50%"></canvas>    
    <script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById("totalViewChart").getContext("2d");
      var labels = ["Feb 01"];
      var data = [120];

      var totalViewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: labels, // lineChartLabels has to be passed here
          datasets: [{
            label: "No. of Viewers",
            data: data, // lineChartData has to be passed here.
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)"],
            borderColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)"],
            borderWidth: 1,
          }, ],
        },
        options: {
          animation: false,
          width: 600,
          height: 100,
          responsive: false,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales: {y: {beginAtZero: true,},},
        },
      });
    </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

**Desired Output from static code**
[image]

**Code Tried:**

```
<script data-test="<%= lineChartData %>">
var ctx = document.getElementById("totalViewChart<%= i %>").getContext("2d");
        
var labels = JSON.stringify("<%= lineChartLabels %>");
const getTest = document.currentScript.dataset.lineChartData;
var data = [120];
        
var totalViewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: getTest,
        data: data, // lineChartData has to be passed here.
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)"],
        borderColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)"],
        borderWidth: 1,
        }, ],
      },
      options: {
      animation: false,
      width: 600,
      height: 100,
      responsive: false,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {y: {beginAtZero: true,},},
    },
  });
</script>
```

**OUTPUT of Code Tried**
[image]

**Try2**

```
<script data-test="<%= lineChartData %>">
    var ctx = document.getElementById("totalViewChart<%= i %>").getContext("2d");

    var labels = "<%= JSON.stringify(lineChartLabels) %>";
    const getTest = document.currentScript.getAttribute("data-test");
    const data = "<%= JSON.stringify(lineChartData) %>"
    var data2 = [120];

    var totalViewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: data,
          data: data,
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
        }, ],
      },
   ...
   </script>
```

**Output: Try2**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use ejs variables inside `<script>` tag in html?

You can, although you need to keep in mind that the parsing rules for source code inside a `<script>` element are different to most of the rest of HTML. This means that `<%=` is unsuitable and you need to use `<%-` combined with some custom escaping to make you safe from XSS attacks.

> I need to use the variable created with ejs syntax to the script part of the file.

I'd suggest using `data` attributes for this.

```
<script data-test="<%= test  %>">
    const getTest = document.currentScript.dataset.test;
</script>
```

Or if the value is an object (including arrays), use JSON:

```
<script data-test="<%= JSON.stringify(test)  %>">
    const getTest = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.dataset.test);
</script>
```

> But in the line `var getTest = <%= test  %>;` it shows me error *Expression expected*

That looks like a bug in your IDE or whatever plugin it is using to parse EJS / HTML / JS syntax.

Comment: The solution you provided worked. But when I try `<% var test = [1,2]; %>` it shows undefined.
can you please help me solve this?

Comment: And I am using VSCode for the code. What are the possible bugs for this?
and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: The output of `<%=` will be a string. So `var test = [1,2];` will give you `data-test="1,2"` which [works just fine when I test it](https://jsbin.com/?html,console). I can't reproduce your problem. (Although you probably want to `JSON.stringify` the value before inserting it into the attribute).

Comment: I updated my question and added a code snippet to understand my use case better. can you please check it?

Comment: @ravipatel0508 — Since that code doesn't show your attempt to follow my recommendations, it isn't very helpful.

Comment: I updated the question and added another snipper with the outputs. please do check it.

Comment: @ravipatel0508 — Re edit: `var labels = JSON.stringify("<%= lineChartLabels %>");` — I said that `<?=` converts them from objects to strings in a way that breaks them. You need to convert them **inside** the EJS. You are currently passing the broken value to client-side JS and then having the client-side code convert the broken data to JSON.  `<script data-test="<%= JSON.stringify(lineChartData) %>">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252614/discussion-between-ravipatel0508-and-quentin).

Comment: Re try 2: `<script data-test="<%= lineChartData %>">` — You forgot `JSON.stringify`

Comment: `var labels = "<%= JSON.stringify(lineChartLabels) %>";` — No. Do this in the `data-*` attribute.

Comment: `const getTest = document.currentScript.getAttribute("data-test");` — You need to `JSON.parse` this, and `dataset.test` is provided so you don't need to use `getAttribute`.

Comment: `const data = "<%= JSON.stringify(lineChartData) %>"` — No. Do this in the `data-*` attribute.

Comment: Finally, everything worked perfectly and `dataset.test` is not working for me it worked with `getAttribute` for me.
One more doubt, I need this Chart more than 1 time on my page and so I am using the EJS `for` loop starting just after the variable initialization to the end of the script.
with this solution, I am getting the chart 1st time, and the rest of the graph is not showing.